# Share sheet in swift .Iphone

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, share, app

Делаю приложение ,где можно делиться контентом. Я сделал кнопку 'share' , но она по стандарту вызывает  меню снизу и иконки приложений которые доступны.

Вопрос: Можно ли сделать это меню 'share in other app' под свой дизайн ? 
В интернете не нашел ничего интересного по этому поводу, если имеется хороший источник на эту тему, буду благодарен за сылку )

Comment: Бросьте эту затею — share sheet должен быть нативным элементом iOS, чтобы пользователь сразу понимал что к чему, никому не нужен Ваш дизайн, я уверен.

Comment: Хорошо , спасибо за комментарий. Но мне все же интересно, возможно ли это вообще сделать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так можно сделать. Сделайте свою кнопку, повесьте на нее обработчик, который покажет ваш собственный UI - иными словами, не вызывайте ничего связанного с UIActivityViewController, а реализуйте все с нуля. Правда, в таком случае придется самому делать не только UI, но и логику этого экрана.

Comment: Если я буду так делать и захочу делиться в соц. сети , то мне придется под каждую кнопку делать ссылки , контент и внешний вид. Так получается ?

Comment: Верно, именно так.